# Seams on cube edges when using texture atlas with three.js

Tags: three.js, texture-mapping, uv-mapping, texture-atlas

I have seams between horizontal faces of the cube when use texture atlas in three.js.
This is demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rnix/gtxcj3qh/7/ or http://jsfiddle.net/gtxcj3qh/8/ (from comments)

Screenshot of the problem:
[image: seams]
Here I use repeat and offset:

```
    var materials = [];
    var t = [];
    var imgData = document.getElementById("texture_atlas").src;
    for ( var i = 0; i < 6; i ++ ) {
      t[i] = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( imgData ); //2048x256
      t[i].repeat.x  = 1 / 8;
      t[i].offset.x = i / 8;
      //t[i].magFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
      t[i].minFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
      t[i].generateMipmaps = false;
      materials.push( new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: t[i], overdraw: 0.5 } ) );
    }

    var skyBox = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.CubeGeometry( 1024, 1024, 1024), new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials) );
    skyBox.applyMatrix( new THREE.Matrix4().makeScale( 1, 1, -1 ) );
    scene.add( skyBox );
```

The atlas has size 2048x256 (power of two). I also tried manual UV-mapping instead of repeat, but the result is the same. I use 8 tiles instead of 6 because I have thought precision of division 1/6 causes the problem, but not.

Pixels on this line are from next tile in atlas. I tried completly white atlas and there was not any artefacts. This explains why there are not seams on vertical borders of Z-faces. I have played with filters, wrapT, wrapS and mipmaps but it does not help. Increasing resolution does not help. There is 8192x1024 atlas http://s.getid.org/jsfiddle/atlas.png  I tried another atlas, the result is the same.

I know that I can split atlas into separate files and it works perfectly but it is not convenient.

Whats wrong?

Comment: Not an answer, but improved your fiddle a bit: http://jsfiddle.net/gtxcj3qh/8/.

Comment: I expanded your fiddle and made it work by using canvas as bitmap source instead of an image (http://jsfiddle.net/gtxcj3qh/14/). The original image is tile by tile painted on a separate canvas, which is then used to create a separate texture. I've asked a very similar question here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43401684/uv-mapping-a-cube-in-three-js-not-joining-faces-correctly) .. but instead of using your approach I've created a custom UV map and a single texture ... however the result was the same as yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is the filtering problem with texture sheets. On image borders in a texture sheet, the gpu may pick the texel from either the correct image or the neighbor image due to limited precision. Because the colors are usually very different, this results in the visible seams. In regular textures, this is solved with CLAMP_TO_EDGE.

If you must use texture alias, then you need to fake CLAMP_TO_EDGE behavior by padding the image borders. See this answer https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/61796/sprite-sheet-textures-picking-up-edges-of-adjacent-texture. It should look something like this: (exaggerated borders for clarity)

[image]

Otherwise, the simpler solution is to use a different texture for each face. Webgl supports the cube texture and that is usually used the majority of the time to implement skyboxes.

Comment: "Exaggerated borders" is not perfect solution. Probably, there is no perfect solution at all.

Comment: I agree that exaggerated edges are not a good solution, however this idea gave me an inspiration to find the solution to this problem.The solution is to arrange the tiles in such way that they are adjacent to tiles they will be adjacent in 3D object. That way their edges will touch the ones they will be touching in 3D object. A more detailed description of this solution can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43401684/uv-mapping-a-cube-in-three-js-not-joining-faces-correctly (it's partially duplicated question/answer, since a different method of applying texture was used)

Answer (score 2):

Hack the uv, replace all value `1.0` with `0.999`, replace all value `0` with `0.001` will fakely resolve part of this problem.

Comment: Thanks, this solved my skybox edges / seams issue completely!

Comment: I had the same problem, with a skybox single texture like a fallen cross, in blender. I created a cube in blender, then i subdivide it 10x with 1.0 smoothnees to create a skysphere, the point is the cube has exactly that skybox initial UV shape! The best way til now is to edit the UV where the problem happens, like you said, but we lose a few lines of pixels to fix that black line and this doesnt mean the result will be bad. Is much better than editing 50+ skybox textures. Also, instead of black background i am using transparent, what may lower the problem depending on the project.